# JSON to Javascript serialisation/deserialisation validation

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, validation

A lot of times we come across code where we use JSON format without actual data contract validation. e.g. I have a ASP.Net server side code which returns a serialized answer to Javascript client. Further this client uses some of the values within the response to make other server side calls. Though not very frequent but we do see issues where someone increased the data type on server side breaking client side in really bad way. I am looking for suggestions how can I implement a proper build time validation system to avoid such issues

Let me explain with a hypothetical example. Client makes a call to `getCars(int employeeID)` ==> Response object has `List<CarIDs, CarNames>`. Using `CarIDs` iterative calls are made from UI to `getCarDetails(CarID)`. Now earlier the data type of `CarID` was `int`, which recently got updated to long. Javascript had a limitation to handle only upto 15 digits numbers, so on the client side any digits are de-serialization are rounded up. This caused inaccuracy in results.

Let me know if there are any suggestions on how I can implement some validation/contract upfront to get rid of such issues.

Answer (score 0):

The [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) is designed exactly for this purpose and the excellent JSON.NET library supports it.

Comment: If your C# controller is set up to accept a plain class (just properties, no methods) then the mapper will fill out that object properly.  It can even accept arrays and nested data.